# WebClient.DownloadFile download file that is dynamically created

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a file that is dynamically created (ie I request it via a handler `http://example.com/images/1849?encoding=UTF-8&b=100`) It creates the image based on what attributes you pass in. I am trying to figure out how to use `WebClient.DownloadFile` to grab this file but cannot get it to work has anyone done this before? The error does not tell me anything "System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

```
  WebClient Client = new WebClient();
  Client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/images22?encoding=UTF-8&b=100", @"c:\myfile.jpeg");
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders My Apologies, I dont think that deserved a down vote though. I am simply trying to find someone that has implemented the way I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't comment, need rep...

Have you tried wrapping the `DownloadFile` in a `Try / Catch` block and then displaying the error details?  Specifically, if it's a HTTP error, or some other system error?

Answer (score 1):

The second string parameter is a local file to download to, such as `C:\image.bmp`.

You could instead use `DownloadData` if you want a byte array to work with instead.

Comment: Haha sorry forgot to include that when I was writing it.